# create parent and child product structure

Tags: e-commerce

I ma new in **Worpress**  i have product data  parent and child structure  basically  i worked in  **magento**.
in **magento** i create  product **(configurable for parent products)**and **(simple product for child products)**. 
but in **wordpress** i don't know how to create like parent and child products Products structure Please help me how can i do it? 
one more thing i have a large catalog so i have to import Data from Csv File 
I will be very tankful Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you need is WooCommerce. With WC you can create a product, set it as a 'Variable Product', and create individual variations with their own prices, SKUs etc. that customers will be able to choose from a dropdown in your store. As for importing data from a .CSV, there are plenty of plugins out there that will allow you to do this.

WordPress isn't like Magento in that all it is is a website building tool. If you want to do more with your site, you need Plugins or custom code, the former being the much simpler solution.

Comment: thanks yes i used variation plugin its working but when i import from csv there not importing variations products

Answer (score 0):

While Magento is inherently e-commerce solution, WordPress is not. So there aren't *inherently* “products” in it.

Any non–native content types in WP are typically expressed and implemented as *Custom Post Types*. There are no hierarchical relationships between them or post relationships at all natively.

As such it is very unclear what your described Magento concept would map as is in WordPress site. I would guess you would want to look into WP e-commerce plugins first, not re–invent it from scratch.